# What is Jaguar in response headers

Tags: http, web

What is **Jaguar** (v3.0-11) in my response headers?

[image]

Comment: you can tag the browser also i think - chrome / firefox etc

Comment: It looks like you're using a proxy and the proxy is adding its own headers. Jaguar is the name of the proxy server's software.

Comment: It could be a reference to Sybase EAServer (Jaguar CTS)